# My profile and applications disappeared

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs

I had carefully crafted a profile and applied for several positions. The profile was migrated from Careers.

This morning I received an email notification about a message from a recruiter. I clicked to reply and got presented with dialog asking me to link my Stack Overflow account. Without a lot of thinking I clicked *Yes* and my nice, valuable profile and all applications associated with it disappeared. I was already logged in to my Stack Overflow account when I clicked on the link in the email.

Email is genuine coming from `reply-258230-1471571-be1a6b69f46e40968e280c57c7a717c2@reply.careers.stackoverflow.com`

I figured out where the profile went. User experience is not consistent. On the profile page, the Developer Story is there:

> [image]

However if you go to Messages, Developer Story is missing:

> [image]

Is there a way to get my applications and profile back?

My applications are still missing which is frustrating.

Comment: Your post here is incredibly calm considering that we're talking about employment matters.  Props to you for clearly laying out the issue despite what I'm sure is a pretty trying time.

Comment: Just to put your mind at ease: nothing has gone. Investigating now

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler as a developer I understand that when such a large migration as moving from Careers to Jobs is taking place edge cases like this one are likely to happen. I am also a calm guy. :)

Comment: Thanks @DeanWard. I understand that nothing is _lost_. I guess that my applicatio get somehow orphaned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** There were multiple Careers accounts at play here; one of them received a message and then your SO account ended up being linked to an older CV. Fix was to merge the newly linked user into your original Careers user.

I'm a little confused. You've opted into the developer story beta which (during the beta period) has no effect on your CV or applications. When I view your developer story it is populated from an import that you did from your CV.

In the 'Jobs' tab there is a 'messages' tab - when I check your account I can see there are messages from today and there continues to be an 'edit CV' button that allows you to edit the CV (profile) you use for applying to jobs.

The only other thing I can think of is that you may have been logged into another account on SO, but I can see no evidence of that on the backend.

Can you let us know if this is still a problem?

Comment: Yes it is. Could you find the application that was confirmed by this message `E1bEjo0-0001bv-A2@mx-out.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: Developer Story has effect on application for sure. I can send you copy of the application. Developer Story (traditional) was attached to the application. Further on when editing Developer Story it is stated: _Even if you hide the tab, you will be visible to employers if you have expressed interest in being contacted._ and _Share your profile with a link to a chrome-less version of your developer story._ In my understanding that means that employers will see Developer Story. 

I have only one account on StackOverflow.

Comment: I just notice that my favorites are missing as well. :(

Comment: OK, I'm looking into it further. Do you have more than one Careers account or multiple email addresses?

Comment: I found the Careers account associated with the application (it has a different email address to your SO account)... What would you like me to do? I can merge the two accounts, but would need to know which one takes priority - the CVs on the two different accounts will be merged together otherwise.

Comment: Also, although it appears to be the traditional view of the developer story attached to the application, it actually isn't... It's the CV (but which developer story imitates to minimise confusion for employers). Some of the copy in developer story does state things about employers but the key thing to note is that this is *all a beta* and nothing developer story applies to employers just yet. I'll see if we can get the copy clarified in the short term before we actually release it.

Comment: Most likely I opened Careers account or logged in for the first time using the other gmail account that I have. I can't recall honestly. It was a few years ago. :) Careers account should take priority. I am assuming that merge will not affect SO reputation, answers, comments, etc. How is it possible that I applied from the Careers account since Careers website is not active for quite sometime?

Comment: Yup, absolutely no ill effects on your SO account... I'll make sure the CV from the original Careers account takes priority and merge everything else (your messages, favourites, etc.) in. I'll drop a note here when it's done!

Comment: My SO CV is missing details on my current employment. Those details are included in the generated CV sent along with application. Therefore, by all means it is Developer Story that is sent to employers. Send me an email and I will forward you the confirmation I received.

Comment: You SO account has [this CV](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/edit/200855) associated with it (as well as a dev story which looks like an import of that CV). Suspect that was what was attached to the application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115456/discussion-between-goran-miskovic-and-dean-ward).